# Atom IDE keymapping for ~ in Windows for German keyboards

Tags: atom-editor, keymapping

When typing on a German keyboard Atom IDE has trouble to map certain keys to the characters.

I learnt so far editing keymap.cson helps:

```
'.platform-win32 .editor':
'    ctrl-alt-[': 'unset!'    # for \
'    ctrl-alt-q': 'unset!'    # for @
```

I succeeded to write \ and @ but I failed to map "~", which might be helpful in editing package.json. I tried to add:

```
'    ctrl-alt-]': 'unset!'    # for ~
```

but that didn't do anything.
Has someone a better idea, or even a list with all the characters that need mapping?

I understand this problem is relevant for all non-English keyboards.

Answer (score 1):

A Community Package called [keyboard-localization](https://atom.io/packages/keyboard-localization) solved my problem:

> This is a compatibility package for atom text editor which tries to remap keycodes for your given keyboard layout.